# ExtJS How to submit a form and a store at one request?

Tags: php, ajax, extjs, datagrid, extjs4

Imagine two forms and one grid. Form A consists of comboxes. The boxes show data from database. The user selects the comboboxes and the result is a new record of the grid's store. It is also possible to put new values/records into the comboboxes. (No database insert)
Form B consists of several textfields. Its kind of MasterDetail. Grid is Master, Form B is Detail. At the end i want to submit form B and the grid`s store at one request (ajax). At server-side i want to store the detail data and connect them with existing records or even create new records and connect them. I want to run that operations into transaction context.

Now i don't know what is good/best practise. I tried to use the sync method of the grid`s store and include the form (form B) values as extraParams. That works, but it is possible that after successfull request i need to do another request with same (untouched) store (only form B changes), so i would have to reset records states. (sync performs changes only)

Maybe a simple Ext.ajax.request() would to the job, but how to pass the store? I can add form B values as param, but i don`t know how to add the store? Do i need to add every record item to the params config by my own?

info: server-side is php, db is mysql

Answer (score 1):

```
{// form submit button

            id: 'save-frm',
            text: 'Save',
            handler: function(btn) {
                //btn.setDisabled(true);
                frm = this.up('form').getForm();
                if(frm.isValid()){

                    var store_data = new Array();
                    your_store.each(function(node){
                            store_data.push(JSON.stringify({id: node.data.id, name: node.data.name}))
                    })
                     frm.submit({
                          waitMsg: 'Enregistrement en cours...',
                          submitEmptyText: false, 
                          params:{store_data: JSON.stringify(store_data)}, 
                          success: function(form, action){
                                //
                          },
                         failure: function(form, action){                           
                             //
                         }
                    });
                }
            }
 }
```

You can send your store data as a param of your submit form
or using Ajax.request 
ON PHP side you get store-data using `$store_data = json_decode($_POST['store_data']);`

Answer (score 1):

If Form B values are detailed information about the record, extends the Model to include those fields and simply don't display them in the grid view.
Then every change in Form B would result in a changed record field and therefore an update.

Comment: This.  If it really is master / detail, then the grid and form should share the same store.